# Remove vertical ScrollBar from Lightning Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, html, lightning-design-system

I am relatively new to Salesforce lightning and HTML/CSS. I was trying to create a Custom Grid to display Data with Pagintation(infinite scrolling).

It all went well till i started solving the issue of vertical scroll bar appearing on my page all the time. For pagination, i wanted to display scroll bar only on the grid and not on the entire page(default lightning grid behaviour). The snapshot below explains the problem very well.
[image]

But, as you can see in the snapshot above, there's an extra scroll bar that appears on the page as well. How do i set the

```
{ overflow:hidden;}
```

on the main page?

Comment: reduce the size of you component height. Scroll bar looks like it is needed in the image

Comment: @Eric i have not provided any height for any component. Ideally it should only take the space available right?

Comment: Depending on the classes you used yes. But if you use `slds-frame` for example it will take 100%vh which includes the size of the header which causes it so be larger than the available viewing window. Its a pain really. So you need to get it a bit smaller using css so the scroll bar does not appear. As it is now how do you expect them to see the bottom of your component/page without it? When you scroll the main scroll bar down what do you see below the fold

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to my comments above if you really need to do this it can be added to the init handler as such:

```
document.body.setAttribute('style', 'overflow: hidden;');
```

Which I have used many times to stop scrolling of main window when a modal is displayed.

Comment: That works like a charm. I have been breaking my head over this small for a long time. Thanks Eric.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Eric, this was helpful for me as well. Can you also please have a look on [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227134/how-to-grammatically-identify-if-a-modal-is-open) question posted by me?