# How to programmatically identify that no modal is visible on screen?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, modal, dom

I want to identify that screen does not have any modal visible, and based on this, I want to show or hide the window's default scrollbar.

To show/hide the scrollbar I got excellent solution from [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172937/remove-vertical-scrollbar-from-lightning-page) answer.

Solution :

```
document.body.setAttribute('style', 'overflow: hidden;');
```

This works when we have single modal and we need to toggle scrollbar on open/close of that modal.

However, my case is a bit more dynamic. There may be multiple modals opened one above another. I want that when the last modal is closed, i.e when no modal is open in window, only then show the scrollbar. In the case of answer given above, If out of 2 modals, one modal is closed, the code to show scrollbar is executed and the scrollbar is visible even when one modal is present on screen.

Hence, I want to know possible means to identify presence of modal on screen. Something like this in Bootstrap:

```
if(!$('#myModal').is(':visible')){  //If no modal is visible on screen
  document.body.setAttribute('style', '');   //Remove the style to hide scrollbar
}
```

Please note that I want to identify presence of modal in **DOM** and not in the component where it is rendered.

Comment: We had similar issue and things are working pretty well with [lightning:overlayLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary/documentation)